# C# built in queue faster than my own

Tags: c#, performance

I tried to make a queue that would be so fast as possible and I planned to make it so my taking out many features and you know everything from the beginning. That means I will never try to add more element than I have an array allocated for.

Even though I only implemented what I need, I lose to the built in queue when I get over (~2000) read and write operations.

I got curious what it is that makes the built in queue faster than my own that is built to the bare bone?

As you can see the queue is based on a circular array so I don't have to move any elements. I also just write over the data instead of creating a new node to save some time. (Even though in my test it didn't make any big differences.)

```
class Queue<T> {

    private class Node {
        public T data;
        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public Node() {

        }
    }
    Node[] nodes;
    int current;
    int emptySpot;

    public Queue(int size) {
        nodes = new Node[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            nodes[i] = new Node();
        }
        this.current = 0;
        this.emptySpot = 0;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T value){
        nodes[emptySpot].data = value;
        emptySpot++;
        if (emptySpot >= nodes.Length) {
            emptySpot = 0;
        }
    }
    public T Dequeue() {
        int ret = current;
        current++;
        if (current >= nodes.Length) {
            current = 0;
        }
        return nodes[ret].data;
    }
}
```

My testing code is done with the built in stop watch and everything is written out in ticks.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

    MinimalCollections.Queue<char> queue = new MinimalCollections.Queue<char>(5500);
    Queue<char> CQueue = new Queue<char>(5500);

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5500; i++) {
            queue.Enqueue('f');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5500; i++) {
            queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("My queue method ticks is = {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);

    sw.Reset();

    sw.Start();
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5500; i++) {
            CQueue.Enqueue('f');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5500; i++) {
            CQueue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("C# queue method ticks is = {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The output is:

My queue method ticks is = 2416

C# queue method ticks is = 2320

Comment: Try reversing the tests with C# Queue and your queue. (Do the C# one first, or just repeat the tests multiple times.) If they still show the C# one is faster, take a look at how it was implemented in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/queue.cs,f7cdfd0f848ca249).

Comment: I have tried that, no big differences in performance than the second queue always varies a bit more in between tests. C# built in still a bit faster.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Node` objects here? Couldn't you just have a `T[]`?

Comment: The most obvious difference is that you have an intermediate data container (the `Node` class). So every access costs you an extra dereference, never mind the added work for the GC to traverse the live object graph (which is proportional to the number of live objects). Of course, there is also the possibility you've measured incorrectly; the code you posted here measures JIT time as well as execution time, and does not do multiple iterations of the measurement to average out noise and other factors.

Comment: Isn't CodeReview a better place to be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One obvious overhead that I can see is the introduction of `Node` objects. This will be especially noticeable when you're actually using this as a `Queue` of value types such as `char`, because the built in implementation isn't wrapping the values into a reference type.

Here is how I would change your implementation:

```
class Queue<T>
{
    T[] nodes;
    int current;
    int emptySpot;

    public Queue(int size)
    {
        nodes = new T[size];
        this.current = 0;
        this.emptySpot = 0;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        nodes[emptySpot] = value;
        emptySpot++;
        if (emptySpot >= nodes.Length)
        {
            emptySpot = 0;
        }
    }
    public T Dequeue()
    {
        int ret = current;
        current++;
        if (current >= nodes.Length)
        {
            current = 0;
        }
        return nodes[ret];
    }
}
```

This seems to fare much better (Release build, x64, win 8.1):

```
My queue method ticks is = 582
C# queue method ticks is = 2166
```

Comment: That did it, I removed the Node container, Just stupid me not removing me after changing my mind how I wanted to build it. 

The difference was like nothing until I did a Release build of it and then bam  C# queue skyrocket in time.